# How to count and copy entries with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

currently I am working with an Excel report that has 135.000 rows. There are assets listed in it and I want to count each asset and write it into another worksheet.

I have tried to write a VBA script, which you can find below. It just copies one entry but does not iterate over each row of the worksheet.

```
Sub assetVulnerabilityCount()
    With Sheets("tblExport")
        assetCount = 1
        rowMax = Sheets("tblExport").Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
        currentAsset = Sheets("tblExport").Range("B" & row).Value
            For row = 2 To rowMax

                    If currentAsset = Sheets("tblExport").Range("B" & row).Value Then
                        Sheets("tblTarget").Range("B" & assetCount).Value = Sheets("tblTarget").Range("B" & assetCount).Value + 1

                        Sheets("tblTarget").Range("A" & assetCount).Value = currentAsset
                    Else:
                        currentAsset = Sheets("tblExport").Range("B" & row).Value
                        assetCount = assetCount + 1

                    End If

            Next Zeile
    End With
End Sub
```

Ideally, it would look like this:

```
Worksheet1:
Asset Names:
Laptop1337
Laptop1337
Laptop1337
PC420
PC420

Worksheet2:
Asset Name:    Amount:
Laptop1337     3
PC420          2
```

Worksheet1 is what I have and Worksheet2 is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume rowMax has the number of rows you need to iterate then

```
For row = 2 To rowMax
```

Should loop the rows **if**

```
Next Zeile
```

Is replaced with

```
Next row
```

Since it's `row` that is the variable in the loop.

Comment: Now the compiler says object error(1004) on this line ´currentAsset = Sheets("tblExport").Range("B" & row).Value´

Comment: So which one is undefined? We can't debug your code.

Comment: Okay I did some research on the microsoft page and there it says error number 1004 is connected to copy and paste data. There it says one of these two conditions are true `The Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macro copies and pastes one whole row in an Excel 2003 workbook.
The Microsoft VBA macro copies and pastes a range of 2,516 rows or more rows in an Excel 2003 workbook.` Then they suggest to use something like this: `Range(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("IV" & ActiveCell.Row).End(xlToLeft)).Select` but I am not sure how I can apply this to my code.

Comment: Okay I have now solved the problem and the code runs almost fine! Now I have the problem that the counter counts one unit less than expected, except for the first asset it iterates through